# Zend_Feed_Reader Not supported Schema

Tags: zend-framework, rss, feed, zend-feed

I'm using Zend FW and wanted to make a feed reader. I did the following:

```
$feed = Zend_Feed_Reader::import('feed://blog.lookup.cl/?feed=rss2');
    $data = array(
        'title'        => $feed->getTitle(),
        'link'         => $feed->getLink(),
        'dateModified' => $feed->getDateModified(),
        'description'  => $feed->getDescription(),
        'language'     => $feed->getLanguage(),
        'entries'      => array(),
    );

    foreach ($feed as $entry) {
        $edata = array(
            'title'        => $entry->getTitle(),
            'description'  => $entry->getDescription(),
            'dateModified' => $entry->getDateModified(),
            'authors'       => $entry->getAuthors(),
            'link'         => $entry->getLink(),
            'content'      => $entry->getContent()
        );
        $data['entries'][] = $edata;
    }
```

And it throws the following exception: Scheme "feed" is not supported

The blog was made using Wordpress.

What's wrong? If "feed it's not supported", how can I change the type of feed that Wordpress does?

Thanks in advance,

Take care,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.
I had to put http instead of feed.